# Cannot read property 'sendMessage' of null

Tags: javascript, discord

I am creating my discord bot for my server, and trying to make it say "Welcome" when someone joins the server, and I keep getting an error.

code:

```js
bot.on("guildMemberAdd", function(member) {
    member.guild.channels.find("name", "general").sendMessage(member.toString() + "Wow")

    member.addRole(member.guild.roles.find("name", "Member"));
});
```

Error:

> Cannot read property 'sendMessage' of null

Comment: the error message means `member.guild.channels.find("name", "general") `is null. Before you run that line can you do a simple `console.log(member)` to see the object that is being passed in to the function?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason your `member.guild.channels.find("name", "general")` is being returned as null. We would have to see this function in order to properly debug your problem.